# Frequent cluster upgrades Google container engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Last night my production container engine cluster was being upgraded repeatedly without any user action from our team.
I want to understand is this frequent for other users too.
If yes then does Google Cloud team notify of these upgrades.
We were not prepared for this hence we experienced significant downtime.
Anyone else also facing similar issues.

Anyone from Container engine team could let us know what is happening here?

Comment: Do you mean upgraded or repaired? Have you filed an issue with Google's cloud support team?

Comment: I will file a ticket soon. 
To answer your other question in cloud console cluster showed as being upgraded and also there were duplicate pods for each service stuck in running state and not actually reachable. Also kubernetes dashboard service was unavailable

Comment: I'm curious if you can tell whether the master or nodes were being upgraded.

Comment: From console none of them seemed upgraded only showed status as being upgraded. I will dig through logs and come up with more info on this. But this has happened atleast once before this.
I am pretty sure we didn&#39;t trigger any repair or upgrade. Also nodes or master didn&#39;t change any values.
 Node auto repair was 'enabled' but I was under the impression that repair didn&#39;t cause any downtime or stuck pods.

Comment: Just to add to this, kubernetes sort of caused a dos attack on my database as all those stuck pods couldn't release their connections and kubernetes kept launching pods.

Comment: Update: Support people tell me that it is due to infrastructure upgrade on the nodes. According support I should have only experienced performance degradation and not downtime. Still trying to understand how to avoid this in future.